# .NET: Is Type.GetHashCode guaranteed to be unique?

Tags: .net, clr

I have someone using Type.GetHashCode as if it were a primary key. I think this is a horrible idea but I wanted to know if there was some sort of documented special case that says no two types would have the same hash code.

Comment: .NET has a very strong guarantee that the Type reference for an object will always match when the object is of the same type.  Add to this that it also has a very strong implementation for Object.GetHashCode, it actually dedicates a field in the object to store it.  And you can conclude that it is *very* well distributed.  Not unique, of course, you'd use Type.GUID for that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are no guarantees around GetHashCode except that it will likely be *randomly distributed*, not unique. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) specifically mentions that:

> The default implementation of the GetHashCode method **does not
>   guarantee unique return values for different objects**. Furthermore,
>   the .NET Framework does not guarantee the default implementation of
>   the GetHashCode method, and the value it returns will be the same
>   between different versions of the .NET Framework. Consequently, the
>   default implementation of this method must not be used as a unique
>   object identifier for hashing purposes. ... if two objects do not compare as equal, the GetHashCode methods for the two object **do not have to return different values**.

Random distribution is encouraged to avoid hash collisions (slow Dictionaries):

> For the best performance, a hash function must generate a random
>   distribution for all input.

It is also a very bad idea to persist results of GetHashCode and base any decisions on this persisted value. The same object may return different hash code on a next application execution:

> The GetHashCode method for an object must consistently return the same
>   hash code as long as there is no modification to the object state that
>   determines the return value of the object's Equals method. Note that
>   this is true only for the current execution of an application, and
>   that a **different hash code can be returned if the application is run
>   again**.

CLR itself [changed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/10/24/482447.aspx) GetHashCode implementation for a String between .NET 1 and .NET 2 and uses different hash algorithm for 32 and 64 bit versions.

From [Guidelines and rules for GetHashCode](http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/):

> GetHashCode is designed to do only one thing: balance a hash table. Do
>   not use it for anything else.

You should be looking at [cryptographic hashes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/08/27/hash-functions-in-net-right-tool-for-the-right-job.aspx) if you want  *almost* unique hashcode based on the object value.

Answer (score 8):

It's *not* guaranteed to be unique.

If your assemblies are strongly named you could use the fully qualified type name as a unique key to identify a `Type`.

Comment: Additionally: There is no guarentee that the hashcode for framework classes will stay the same between versions of the runtime.

Comment: The fully qualified name cannot be a key since different instances of the same object type would collide.  Hash codes need to be derived based on the data contained in the object with the goal (but no guarantee) of being as unique as possible to avoid collisions.

Comment: @bryanmac: Maybe I misread the question, but I thought the whole point was that he wants the same value if he has two different objects that have the same type?

Answer (score 1):

The goal of producing a hash code for an object is to be as unique as possible given the type of data to avoid collisions in the table.  But, it's absolutely not guaranteed.  Many hash table implementations chain (an array list) off of each hash code bucket to deal with collisions.