# Example of Mod 256 checksum in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I can't seem to find a lot of information on this checksum algorithm and nothing about in relating to C#, I have a scenerio as follows;

I have a string of data e.g.:

```
string input = "hello world"
```

and I would like to create a checksum, that I can later verify it with the same string

Comment: Could you describe better what you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is enough for you. Mod 256 is automatically implied if you use a byte as checksum.

```
  string s = "hello world";
  byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
  byte check = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
  {
    check += data[i];
  }
```

Comment: I would like to use a byte as a checksum

Comment: As you see the checksum is a byte in my example. See "check"

Comment: Its still not clear whether the bytes are simply added or XOR'ed from your question. So feel free to change the addition to a XOR. So until we have more information this is all that can be helped.

Answer (score 2):

`(byte) input.GetHashCode()`?.........

Comment: just decompiled the code: http://pastebin.com/CdXBYKBY ... any reason, why exactly it should be Mod256? ... checksum is checksum, isn't it?

Comment: `(byte)input.GetHashCode()` There goes your mod 256.

Comment: Question is what he really wants to do. Its still not clear whether "someone else" said to make use of Mod256 checksum algorithm or if he just wants quickly compare strings.

Comment: @KooKiz :) absolutely...

Comment: @BlueM for me "and I would like to create a checksum, that I can later verify it with the same string" dents rather to a hash, which is a wider range than byte ... but yes, question should be more clear :)

Comment: Bad answer, don't use default `GetHashCode()` as unique key or check num: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7458183/6859121 ; but `unchecked((byte)bigNumber)` results is equals to `(byte)(bigNumber % 256)`

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to byte array and calc the checksum:

```
string input = "hello world";
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
var array = enc.GetBytes(input);
byte chksum = 0;
foreach(byte data in array)
{
   chksum += data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checksum, by default, is a simple binary XOR of the whole data to produce a single numeric descriptor of the contents. Normally, the width of the XOR checksum is 32 or 64 to match the size of the platform's word to make it quicker to calculate, those sums are respectively modulo 2^32 and 2^64. If someone said modulo256, then probably he wants a single-byte, 8-bit, thus modulo 256 checksum.

That measn, that you just simply GetBytes from the string, and XOR them all together.