# Is there a guranteed uniqueness for GetType().GetHashCode()?

Tags: c#, gethashcode, gettype

Let's say I have a few classes:

```
MyClass1() {}

MyChild1() : MyClass1 {}

MyChild2() : MyClass2 {}

MyGrandchild1() : MyChild2 {}
```

etc.

I know that GetHashCode() by itself, **does not** guarantee uniqueness between any two different *Objects*, but I'm interested does that apply for any two *Types* as well? i.e.:

**(1)** is there a *chance* that: `typeof(MyClass1).GetHashCode() == typeof(MyGrandchild1).GetHashCode()` will return `true`?

**(2)** if there's a chance for (1): is there a *chance* that `typeof(MyClass1) == typeof(MyGrandchild1)` will return `true`?

**(3)** worst case scenario: is there a *chance* that `typeof(int) == typeof(long)` will return `true`?

**EDIT** I forgot to ask about case **(4)** `typeof(int).GetHashCode() == typeof(long).GetHashCode()`, is there a *chance* for that to return `true`?

Comment: 1. Yes; 2. No; 3. No

Comment: `GetHashCode()` returns integer value. So there is limited count of possible unique values. On other hand there is no limit for different types you can have. So answer is no, there is no guaranteed uniqueness. `GetHashCode()` for different types might be same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET: Is Type.GetHashCode guaranteed to be unique?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458139/net-is-type-gethashcode-guaranteed-to-be-unique)

Comment: @Fabjan if it was only (1) I would agree that it is a full duplicate but as (2) and (3) are also part of the question it sounds like the OP is confused there about equality of types and nonequality of them which makes this question different imho.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy _So there is only about 32k possible unique values._ Isn't [`int`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx) a 32-bit type? There sould be 2^32 possible unique values not only 32k (HashCodes are allowed to be negative).

Comment: @Verarind to what 32k are you refering? (don't see that anywhere and his post hasn't been edited)

Comment: Take a look at the ["Pigeonhole Principle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). There are 2^32 possible hash codes, and an infinite number of possible types.

Comment: @Thomas SergeyBerezovskiy changed his comment. I quoted the text part that contains the 32k you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `GetHashCode` returns an integer, so there is a limit of unique values it can return. There is no limit of defined types, so yes, there is a chance that `typeof(MyClass1).GetHashCode() == typeof(MyGrandchild1).GetHashCode()` will return `true`.

2,3. Hash code is **never** used to check equality. The only relation between hash code and equality is that equal objects should have the same hash code.

**Edit**

One more answer, plus a some explanations.

4. Types implement reference equality. The CLR makes sure the instances are unique

> A Type object that represents a type is unique; that is, two Type object references refer to the same object if and only if they represent the same type. This allows for comparison of Type objects using reference equality.

It means that `Type` can use (and it does) the standard `object` implementation of `GetHashCode`. This implementation returns a pseudo-random number when it's first called on each instance.

So asking if `typeof(int).GetHashCode()` can be equal to `typeof(long).GetHashCode()` is basically asking if two pseudo-random numbers can be equal. Yes they can.

If you want more details about `object.GetHashCode()` implementation, read [this blog post](http://viktorpeller.com/2014/03/18/gethashcode/)

Comment: isn't it used in any kind of a hash table, such as Dictionary<T, T> ?

Comment: @avance70 It's used to assign items to buckets. If you implement `GetHashCode()` as `return 1` in `MyClass`, `Dictionary<MyClass, SomeOtherClass>` will still work correctly, but all items will be stored in a single bucket. Only performance will suffer, as retrieving items will now be O(n) instead of close to O(1).

Comment: thanks! and what about **(4)** `typeof(int).GetHashCode() == typeof(long).GetHashCode()`, is there a _chance_ for that to return `true`?

Comment: @avance70 I just added a lot more details to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that GetHashCode() by itself, does not guarantee uniqueness between any two different Objects, but I'm interested does that apply for any two Types as well

A `Type` *is an object* so the same applies

> is there a chance that: `typeof(MyClass1).GetHashCode() == typeof(MyGrandchild1).GetHashCode()` will return `true`

Yes

> if there's a chance for (1): is there a chance that `typeof(MyClass1) == typeof(MyGrandchild1)` will return `true`

No, they are different types

> worst case scenario: is there a chance that `typeof(int) == typeof(long)`will return `true`

No, for the same reason as above.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Yes there is a chance that `typeof(MyClass1).GetHashCode() == typeof(MyGrandchild1).GetHashCode()` would be `true`. This should make sense as an `int` has a lesser number of possible values that all the possible class names that you could define. There would mathematically have to be collisions.

(2) No, because `System.Type` has a properly implemented `Equals` method. The purpose of the `Equals` method is not only indicate equality, but to "break the tie" when `GetHashCode()` produces a collision.

(3) No. See (2).

Comment: what about **(4)** `typeof(int).GetHashCode() == typeof(long).GetHashCode()`, is there a _chance_ for that to return `true`?

Comment: @avance70 - Yes, but very unlikely. It would possibly be a breaking change for someone's code so Microsoft wouldn't do it.

Comment: `Type` doesn't define any special `GetHashCode` implementation. It uses `object.GetHashCode()`, which returns a pseudo-random number when it's first called on each instance. So it is very likely that sooner or later these 2 hash codes will be the same.

Comment: @JakubLortz - That's very interesting. I guess that would work just fine as `Equals` would handle the rare tie-breaker cases.