Is it a good idea to use a long hashcode as primary key in a database?
I have a Siemens panel that saves alarm records in a csv file. This file has some fields, like an int to codify a date time with milliseconds, a string for a readable date time, and some other fields, about 20 fields.
in this file, the panel saves the new records at the end of the file, until a maximum number, 10000 records. When it is saved the last record, the next it is saved in the first row of the csv file. So it is cycle.
I would like to save these records in a SQL Server database.
For that, I have a process that read the file every 5 or 10 minutes, so before try to save the files in the database, I need to know which records are new to try to save only the new records.
However, the .csv file doesn't have any unique field, I could have two records with the same date time with milliseconds and the same information in the fields, so in this case, I would considerate both records the same.
The problem is that in the database I can't set a primary key composed of 20 fields, so I need to create a key for the record.
What I was thinking to create a class, with one property for each field and an one more property for an ID, that it would be set as the hash of the class.
internal class Alarma
{
    public long Id { get; init; }

    public long TimeMs { get; init; }
    public int MsgProc { get; init; }
    public int StateAfter { get; init; }
    public int MsgClass { get; init; }
    public int MsgNumber { get; init; }
    public string? Var1 { get; init; }
    public string? Var2 { get; init; }
    public string? Var3 { get; init; }
    public string? Var4 { get; init; }
    public string? Var5 { get; init; }
    public string? Var6 { get; init; }
    public string? Var7 { get; init; }
    public string? Var8 { get; init; }
    public string? TimeString { get; init; }
    public string? MsgText { get; init; }
    public string? Plc { get; init; }

    private Alarma()
    {
        Id = this.GetHashCode();
    }

    public Alarma(long parmaTimeMs, int paramMsgProg, int paramStateAfeter, int paramMsgClass, int paramMsgNumber,
        string? paramVar1, string? paramVar2, string? paramVar3, string? paramVar4, string? paramVar5, string? paramVar6, string? paramVar7, string? paramVar8,
        string? paramTimeString, string? paramMsgText, string? paramPlc)
    {
        TimeMs = parmaTimeMs;
        MsgProc = paramMsgProg;
        StateAfter = paramStateAfeter;
        MsgClass = paramMsgClass;
        MsgNumber = paramMsgNumber;
        Var1 = paramVar1;
        Var2 = paramVar2;
        Var3 = paramVar3;
        Var4 = paramVar4;
        Var5 = paramVar5;
        Var6 = paramVar6;
        Var7 = paramVar7;
        Var8 = paramVar8;
        TimeString = paramTimeString;
        MsgText =paramMsgText;
        Plc = paramPlc;

        Id = this.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Alarma other)
        {
            return TimeMs == other.TimeMs
                && MsgProc == other.MsgProc
                && StateAfter == other.StateAfter
                && MsgClass == other.MsgClass
                && MsgNumber == other.MsgNumber
                && Var1 == other.Var1
                && Var2 == other.Var2
                && Var3 == other.Var3
                && Var4 == other.Var4
                && Var5 == other.Var5
                && Var6 == other.Var6
                && Var7 == other.Var7
                && Var8 == other.Var8
                && TimeString == other.TimeString
                && MsgText == other.MsgText
                && Plc == other.Plc;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public long GetHashCode()
    {
        long hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 31 + TimeMs.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + MsgProc.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + StateAfter.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + MsgClass.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + MsgNumber.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + (Var1?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
        hash = hash * 31 + (Var2?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
        hash = hash * 31 + (Var3?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
        hash = hash * 31 + (Var4?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
        hash = hash * 31 + (Var5?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
        hash = hash * 31 + (Var6?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
        hash = hash * 31 + (Var7?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
        hash = hash * 31 + (Var8?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
        hash = hash * 31 + (TimeString?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
        hash = hash * 31 + (MsgText?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
        hash = hash * 31 + (Plc?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);

        return hash;
    }
}

But I don't know if it is a good idea to use a hashcode as primary key because I could have collisions and lose some rows.
Would there be any other options?
Thanks.

"because I could have collisions and lose some record." So you already gave yourself the answer. When there's nothing unique in the file, how do you expect any uniqueness in the database? The only thing you may do is use the line-number as identifier.

What version of SQL Server are you on? The limit is 32 columns in a composite index on recent versions. Is the problem the key length rather than column count? If so hashing is the usual solution for this and hash collisions are so unlikely to not be worth worrying about with any decent algorithm (as long as you don't introduce collisions in the way you concatenate the input to it) - but don't use GetHashCode - you can have a computed column using the HASHBYTES function

@MakePeaceGreatAgain Perhaps I was not very clear. I wanted to generate a hashset to can now if the record is stored in the database or not, to avoid to insert it again, and get know the new records.

@MartinSmith My idea it is to use Sql Server 2022 Express. Although Sql Server allows a composite index of 32 fields, I am wondering if really it is a good idea, although if Sql Server allows it, perhaps it is not so bad solution.

Why not just move the file into a new location once in a while (or empty it if the program cannot handle no file). This way you won't have any dups.

The hash = hash * 31 maths is reminiscent of Bloch's Effective Java. Despite the comments in that book about 31 being prime and magically fixing everything to avoid overflows, you're going to overflow the hash result and only have a distinct result for the last 12 or 13 properties. Everything before that will not affect the result so your hash code isn't very hash-y. There's a reason Microsoft's GetHashCode() examples use ^ (xor) when combining hash codes.

@siggemannen I could do that, in fact I copy the file every 5 or 10 minutes (I can cofigure that). The problem is that the panel only save 10000 records in the csv, the record 10001 is saved in the first position, so I would lost this record. I wanted to use the database to don't lose this records. Also, if I want to get the records to create some charts, I think it is better to work with a database than with a csv file.

@siggemannen Another option it would be create a new file if the first one is full, so I could have alarm0, alarm1 and so on. But if I would like to create some charts, I would have to search in all the files, I think it is not the best option.

What i mean is you do something like: 1. Move file records.csv to records.csv._to_import 2. Empty out records.csv 2. Import records.csv._to_import into db 3. ??? 4. Profit

@siggemannen it is an option, but if I want to get all the records of search data in a rage of dates, I would have to search in all the files, and  to check how many files I have. I think it is better to use a database for that.

See the step #2, it imports stuff into the database

@siggemannen You are right, I didn't understand at first.

This is what I like to call the poor man's primary key. Why not just use all the fields together to make a big primary key covering as many columns as you can?

No
For one, in .NET built-in implementations of GetHashCode aren't warranted to be stable among versions, so your primary keys may change suddenly if you update your .NET Framework (even a minor patch might do that). It's not even warranted to be stable among executions of your program! See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7458183/2557263
Collisions, as you say, are another possibility that puts this schema an impossible problem.
For those situations, a surrogate key is a good option. A simple incremental number DB generated (the IDENTITY in SQL Server) or a GUID (fundamentally a random number) are good options if you can't find a real key within your data.

I was thinking in a surrogate key, but in Sql Server it is possible to have a new record with a lower surrogate than and exisiting record. I would like to have some way to know which is the last record that I have in the databse, so I can get only the nexts records form the csv file.

And what about if I create a field that is a string that concatenate all the columns of the row in the csv file?

An incremental, database-generated identity column will provide ordering in addition to uniqueness, as long as you don't override it. A timestamp column would also do. Concatenating everything is a bad idea, just use all columns as a composite primary key, as long as they're unique.

This is a common issue when importing data from a CSV with no primary key. Use what you can to window the data (like the date/time) then go back a few records to make sure you're definitely looking to import from the right place forwards, so you're matching over a small subset of data rather than trying to use an index for the whole file.

Yes, this is the next step that I didn't detail. But my idea is to get all records from the csv file that is the same date than the last record in the databse, to ensure that I don't lose any record.

That's the right approach. What I would do is get the last 10 records from your database, then turn them into a string and compare that string with the CSV to make sure you're in the right place to import from. You can always do it efficiently by increasing the number of records to compare until you find a unique match for that date.

Faulty, it is another option, I have to think a bit more this part, by the moment I am thinking how to store the data in the database.

With regards to the primary key idea (using a hash) - it's probably not a good idea. What you'd need to do is calculate each row's hash as 512 byte hash including the row in question and going back as many rows as it would typically take for the time stamp to change. This would almost guarantee uniqueness. How many records are we looking at with the exact same timestamp (worst-case)?

There is a very easy answer to your problem, which will save you from having to do anything clever with the primary key (just use a bigint) - if the CSV file contains a date and time. That's all you need to do is import in windows of one minute (so keep track of your last import, and always just import the next minute, but don't try importing anything for this minute). This is a completely foolproof way of importing your data without missing anything.

If you can modify the panel that is generating these records I would just try to update the database directly, without the intermediate file. Ideally using some third party library, like nLog, that support things like structured logging, log archiving, and database targets.
You could also use some IPC/RPC method to run the database code in a separate process or machine if necessary, i.e. create something like a MQTT/gRPC server that publishes events. Have another process subscribe to the events and do whatever needs to be done.
If you insist on using files you could have the panel start over on a new file when it reaches the end. I.e.

Close records.csv
Move records.csv to records_<datetime>.csv
Create a new records.csv and continue writing.

Then you can just check if any records_*.csv exists, process it, and delete it (or archive it). Just make sure you cannot fill the disk if something goes wrong.
If you insist on using hashes to identify rows you at minimum need to use a hashing algorithm that is collision resistant, like SHA256. I would start by trying to create a composite hash-index on all the columns and let the database deal with it.
Regardless of approach you may need to consider how errors are handled. What will happen if power is lost at the worst possible time? Can you lose records? Could records be incomplete or partially written? Could duplicate records be introduced? How serious would such problems be?
